# can't load '**/Encode.so' for module Encode: **/Encode.so: undefined symbol: PL_tainting at **/XSLoader.pm line 68

Tags: perl, undefined

I used my own perl compile several modules and when using, the error occurs:

```
Can't load '**/auto/Encode/Encode.so**' for module Encode:**/auto/Encode/Encode.so: undefined symbol: PL_tainting at **/XSLoader.pm line 68. at **/Encode.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at **/mteval-v13a.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at **/mteval-v13a.pl line 6.
```

In addition, the directory of `Encode.so` in the error line is the same.
Then I recompiled Encode and `XSLoader` using my own perl and when `make install` I found the following lines:

```
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Appending installation info to /leofs/jwb/mqs/6_evn/perl5.20.2//lib/5.20.2/x86_64-linux/perllocal.pod
```

Is there something wrong with the first line? 
Can anyone help me?! I really can't fix it.